# My php script return a 403 error whene i call him

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, http-status-code-403

I have a little problem with PHP:

On my site, I call the PHP script with the fetch method in javascript to dynamically record log files or to list the files in a folder with the PHP blob() function.

My problem is that locally everything works fine, but once on the server, I get the following error with a 403 code:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I tried to put the rules to 777 on the files, nothing to change. I also tried to delete the .htaccess (in case a rule disturbs), but no result.

I dry a bit, and I don't know what to try :/
If you have an idea, I would like to know her!

Thanks for your time :)

EDIT :

After a lot of tests, I discovered that the same code works perfectly on another server... so it's probably the configuration of the server I need to change, but what? I don't know exactly, ^^.

Comment: Make sure the directory you're trying to access is actually the document root of your site.

Comment: the root directory it's "public_html" like i have two site, my website is in a subfolder so the directory i want access is "public_html/website/assets/files/documents".
That can be a problem ? 